# Freelancing from India to USA Employer - Upwork or USA Local Bank Account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, wire-transfer, dtaa

We are a Private Limited Company based in India. Recently I was working on Upwork with our client and now they are willing to work directly with us.

We have 2 options for payment :

1. Continue Upwork (will be company income)
2. I have a USA Chase Account (will be my private income)

Can you please guide me on which will be a better option.  I can either move that money to India or keep it in my Chase Account in the USA.

I would like to understand what will be the tax implications in both cases.
When I keep that money in the USA (I think I have to pay taxes in USA and India Both)

Comment: "We" implies there are others in this company? Or is it really just a pass through company for you to get paid more easily/tax purposes/etc. but it's just you and all the money eventually goes to you?

Comment: on this project I am the only one working so it's ok if the money eventually comes to me either ways